# Authorization header not being sent/seen in Cloud Functions using Fetch

Tags: cors, authorization, google-cloud-functions, fetch, netlify

Seems like I am banging my head against the wall here... I've tried in numerous ways to get a simple Fetch call to send an Authorization header. You can see the demo at https://demo-gcf-auth.netlify.com/.

I've received a number of different CORS errors, but ultimately they all emanate from either Access-Control-Allow-Credentials being wiped (becoming `''`) or more simply that there is no Authorization header in the first place.

The setup is a simple `index.html` hosted on Netlify, with a Google Cloud Function as the backend that should receive a token and then pass it back. This began as a much more elaborate setup, of course, but I am not even getting this extremely minimal version to work. I have also validated the scenario by using a near-equivalent call to an AWS Lambda function, which works perfectly fine. That function has an auto-generated API Gateway in front, but I've specified some baseline CORS settings.

It seems like the pattern to call `res.end()` if the call has an OPTIONS method has been proposed before, but I'm not sure why that would be a good way of handling this. Nonetheless, I am not getting the token returned.

Currently the Authorization header doesn't even seem to be sent, and much less even received in the backend.

Anyone see where this is going wrong?

Please don't propose using the npm `cors` package since that does not help and does nothing that cannot be explicitly programmed without that specific dependency.

I have found a related issue going on at https://community.netlify.com/t/authorization-header-is-undefined/4117.

**Cloud Functions Backend**

```
'use strict';

exports.minimalAuthorization = function(req, res) {
    const ORIGIN = req.headers.origin;
    console.log('ORIGIN', ORIGIN);

    const TOKEN = req.headers.Authorization || req.headers.authorization;
    console.log('TOKEN', TOKEN);

    const METHOD = req.method;
    console.log('METHOD', METHOD);

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ORIGIN);
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*'); // POST, OPTIONS
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'); // Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, authorization

        if (TOKEN) {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(TOKEN));
        } else res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify('Sorry, no token for you...'));
    }
};
```

**Relevant HTML script section**

```
<script>
    const ENDPOINT =
        'https://europe-west1-cloud-developer-basics.cloudfunctions.net/minimalAuthorization';
    const TOKEN = `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImEwYjQwY2NjYmQ0OWQxNmVkMjg2MGRiNzIyNmQ3NDZiNmZhZmRmYzAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.LI2ySD6uafnkruEDDmkym6JKoMdhjOEOGKQiytc3SFyeCDERwylqwsmiaCtE7Q6W_FjqrNaAW2rV09rcvuQFPGAMA8uSGiUCdlwau1tBIENHu_HGdW4wI_PWEi6sRmIpbMPTsIPjpcmsSIcpd_WDtz4EldAboXkottFSS7dU81MDbdgrdwKyaq8y-haJqBtr2LAIHy5rg7leSXyY9wqmj9u4iwExWn-pY6BK7dGCEJFTK0_Czvs3qi-0e8bEPmUXwiKzuuMIL_B9l22EHZXqJv0nd9LIzN5_ofyv63U2rG4DbTgNupRAeibhxUO5djVNtgCcFV49618t9ca81d7znQ`;

    async function callApiWithToken(token) {
        console.log('Calling API with token:', token);

        await fetch(ENDPOINT, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    callApiWithToken(TOKEN);
</script>
```

**Fully functional AWS Lambda equivalent**

```
'use strict';

function minimalAuthorization(event, context) {
    const TOKEN = event.headers.Authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    console.log('TOKEN', TOKEN);

    const ORIGIN = event.headers.origin;
    console.log('ORIGIN', ORIGIN);

    if (TOKEN) {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: TOKEN,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ORIGIN,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
            }
        };
    } else
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: 'Sorry, no token for you...',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ORIGIN,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
            }
        };
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return minimalAuthorization(event, context);
};
```

**Serverless function config, AWS Lambda**

```
functions:
  minimalAuthorization:
    handler: functions/minimalAuthorization.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: minimalAuthorization
          cors:
            origin: 'https://demo-gcf-auth.netlify.com'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: true
```

Comment: Using the Network pane in browser devtools to inspect https://demo-gcf-auth.netlify.com/ shows that the browser is making a CORS preflight OPTIONS request to `https://europe-west1-cloud-developer-basics.cloudfunctions.net/minimalAuthorization` but that preflight fails because the response doesn’t include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. So it seems your current server code isn’t handling the OPTIONS request correctly — at least it’s not causing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be sent in the response to that OPTIONS

Comment: As far as the Authorization request header, it’s expected that the browser won’t include that in the preflight OPTIONS request — because the CORS spec requires browsers to omit it (and anyway, in that OPTIONS request, the browser won’t include *any* headers you set in your frontend code).

Comment: `As far as the Authorization request header, it’s expected that the browser won’t include that in the preflight OPTIONS request [...]` is interesting and surprising to me as [Google's own example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#using_cloud_endpoints_to_handle_cors) (as far as I can tell) precisely sends the auth header if it's an OPTIONS request as per `if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization'); [...]`?

Comment: The Authorization *request* header doesn’t get sent in the OPTIONS *request*. That Google example shows server-side code for handling the *response* to the OPTIONS request. And it doesn’t show the Authorization header being sent — instead it shows the server configured to respond to the OPTIONS request to say, *“I will allow requests that include the Authorization header”*. That’s what the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` response header means.

Comment: Check! And as my own answer indicates, the Authorization header was not sent because the Content-Type was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this should have been a lot more obvious. At various points I've seen the recommendation to always explicitly set the Content-Type (always using the value of `application/json`). THAT was completely false, and should be removed, or set the Content-Type to, for example, `text/plain`. This is documented at http://50linesofco.de/post/2017-03-06-cors-a-guided-tour#credentials-and-cors.

Not quite sure why the same actual HTML would provide a functioning 204+200 response with AWS Lambda though...

Closing. If you are stuck with CORS I am providing the frontend and backend examples to make this work for you, should you require authorization headers.

**Frontent**

```
// CORS mode is default, as is Content-Type: 'text/plain'; both are required
await fetch(ENDPOINT, {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
})
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

**Backend**

```
exports.minimalAuthorization = function(req, res) {
    const TOKEN = req.headers.authorization;
    console.log('TOKEN', TOKEN);

    const METHOD = req.method;
    console.log('METHOD', METHOD);

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://demo-gcf-auth.netlify.com'); // Your origin here
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

    // A 204 response (preflight response) happens before actually trying to respond, so accept the auth header and send an OK
    if (METHOD === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
        res.status(204).send('');
    } else {
        // If it's not an OPTIONS request, actually do send the value/token back
        if (TOKEN) {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(TOKEN));
        } else res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify('Sorry, no token for you...'));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused as to why the backend code sets the origin to the origin header of the request. Guess it’s for testing purposes, but that would mean all requests are valid.

```
const ORIGIN = req.headers.origin;
```

This would be the same as setting

```
const ORIGIN = '*';
```

However, I managed to get your code working with a few tweaks:

```
'use strict';

exports.minimalAuthorization = function(req, res) {
    const ORIGIN = req.headers.origin;
    console.log('ORIGIN', ORIGIN);

    const TOKEN = req.headers.authorization;
    console.log('TOKEN', TOKEN);

    const METHOD = req.method;
    console.log('METHOD', METHOD);

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ORIGIN);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*'); // POST, OPTIONS

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
        res.status(204).send('');
    } else {
        if (TOKEN) {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(TOKEN));
        } else res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify('Sorry, no token for you...'));
    }
};
```

I think the OPTION method needs to return a 2xx response to pass preflight.

Also I moved some of the headers like the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' out of the non OPTIONS response and put the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' inside the OPTIONS response.

I also created a frontend on codepen to test the function:
https://codepen.io/baktakt/pen/KKKyKzp?editors=0011

Comment: I see that you are using the reference implementation that Google shows at [https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#using_cloud_endpoints_to_handle_cors](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#using_cloud_endpoints_to_handle_cors). I've tried it – and did so now as well – however, with same results. Logs don't show the token at all. Further, I only get a successful 204 response but no 200 like you do in your demo. Can you try hosting the HTML at Netlify? I am beginning to strongly suspect something with Netlify not working.

Comment: Regarding `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ORIGIN);` that is functionally the same as using `'*'`, however the asterisk is (AFAIK) blacklisted when you send credentials and will always fail. Therefore, you get the same practical result setting it to the origin. Still a lazy approach but for testing it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Certain request headers, such as Content-Type or custom headers, can trigger a preflight `OPTIONS` request. If the client includes such headers in the request, the cloud function needs to handle the `OPTIONS` request and respond accordingly, otherwise `Authorization` will appear `undefined`.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  
  // Handle OPTIONS request
  if (event.httpMethod === 'OPTIONS') {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
      },
      body: 'OK',
    }
  }

  // Now the Authorization header is available
  const headers = event.headers
  const authHeader = headers['authorization']
  console.log(authHeader) // '123456789'

}
```